# Codeigniter: Using set_select() if dropdown data comes from the db

Tags: codeigniter

I have a dropdown <select> field which gets its values from the db. I'm currently looking for a way to use `set_select()` but have been unsuccessful. Here's my existing view:

```
<select name="userbase">
    <?php echo $userbase_list; ?>
</select>
```

The variable `$userbase_list` is a string containing all the `<option value="">text</option>` html to be inserted. Since this <select> is generated from the db, does that mean I can't use the CI `set_select()` anymore?

Comment: Wait why are you storing them in a string like that if you already have the form helper built into CI?

Comment: Holy crap! You're right! What the hell was I thinking?

Comment: I noticed that `set_select()` doesn't work if you place a default value in `form_dropdown`. I don't want to place a default but I need to get to the 4th parameter so I can apply a class or any other HTML attribute. Is there a way to bypass setting the default entirely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$array_of_options= array("key_one"=>"val_one", "key_two"=>"val_two");

foreach($array_of_options as $k => $v)
{
    $selected = ($v === $db_result) ? 'selected=selected' : '';
    echo '<option '.$selected.' value='.$k.'>' . $v . '</option>';
}
```

Comment: `$selected` needs to be concated to the string too.  I fixed it for you :-)